# G++ для linux: исходный код

Tags: g++, c++, linux

Никак не могу найти **исходный код g++ для linux**. Мне нужен именно исходный код. Много всевозможных источников перерыл и ни к чему толковому это не привело. Нужен он мне для установки на удаленный сервер(там он не установлен и в пакетах к системе его нет), потому что без него не получается установить серверное приложение.
Помогите плз).

Comment: для этого Вам нужен будет gcc, что бы скомпилировать. Да и компилировать нужно будет долго. Проще найти готовый бинарник. Либо с помощью кросскомпиляции собрать на своей машине.

Comment: Насчет долго - зависит от машины. Если только один g++, то не так уж и долго.

Comment: а что за "удаленная система" ? (дистр какой centos/debian)

Comment: А сюда http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/gcc/gppFAQ.html#SEC1 смотрели?

Comment: Удаленная система это сервер. Нужне именно исходник, потому что бинарника в репах нету.

Comment: @boikov "Удаленная система это сервер." ну вы даете... абстрактный сервер в вакууме ? покажите вывод 

    uname -a;cat /etc/redhat* /etc/debian_version 2>/dev/null

Comment: Linux ip-10-49-38-224 3.2.38-5.48.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 13 01:07:25 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Похоже "рация на бронепоезде" продолжается.

@boikov, посмотрите cat /etc/issue и наличие команды apt-get

Comment: Это amazon linux, 

>> Amazon Linux, like CentOS, is based on RHEL -- it is fundamentally a minimal/basic install of Red Hat Enterprise Linux (hence optimised for the purpose)

надо найти версию, попробуйте 

lsb_release -a;cat /etc/*-release 2>/dev/null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://gcc.gnu.org

Прямая ссылка для последней версии ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.0/gcc-4.8.0.tar.bz2

Или с зеркала http://robotlab.itk.ppke.hu/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.0/gcc-4.8.0.tar.bz2

Comment: Вы будете удивлены, но gcc-4.8 написан на... С++. Соответственно, для его компиляции требуется g++. Выход - компилить 4.7

Comment: @skegg А на чем же тогда написан первозданный компилятор для C++?